# Directory.CreateDirectory throws an exception, but only with .NET core?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to log a line to a file, but unfortunately I hit a problem when the directory doesn't exist, the app tries to automatically create the directory and file. It works fine on .NET framework, but not core.

`_filePath` has the contents of (at compile time)

```
_filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "/resources/logging/");
```

Which results in

```
_filePath = "B:\\App\\App\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.0\\App.Core.dll\\resources\\logging"
```

An exception text is printed, here is the content.

> System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot create
>   'B:\App\App\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\App.Core.dll' because
>   a file or directory with the same name already exists.'

Here is the line which throws the above error.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(_filePath);
```

Full method

```
private void LogToFile(string file, string content)
{
    var fullPath = Path.Combine(_filePath, file);

    if (!Directory.Exists(_filePath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(_filePath);
    }

    if (!File.Exists(fullPath))
    {
        File.Create(fullPath);
    }

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_filePath + file, true))
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but you don't need to check if the directory exists first. `Directory.CreateDirectory` already checks to see if the directory exists

Comment: Cute little tip, thanks.

Comment: You can't have more directories after a file name (App.Core.dll). Did you mean to omit the dll file from the path?

Comment: Yes, but I'm saying that this code should work globally, if on .NET framework or core, if that's not built into C# somewhere, I need to know how I can do that myself. I'm not sure why .NET framework returns a directory, but .NET core returns a dll.

Comment: For people wondering, here is how I assigned _filePath. `_filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "/resources/logging/");`

Comment: I just tried it and I get the dll file from the `Location` property in both platforms.

Comment: .NET framework doesn't compile into a DLL like .NET core, so I can't see how this is possible, unless you mean it returns .exe? Either way, the code didn't fire an exception with .NET framework.

Comment: If you also read my question, I call `Path.GetDirectoryName` on that, I would check your testing again.

Comment: Take this part out of the call to GetDirectoryName:  + "/resources/logging/"  and add it to the return of the call.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying, why would I do that? "/resources/logging/" is where I want to store the logging. If you mean remove it to get your result, then your result isn't testing my code, its testing yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided fails with full framework as well. The issue is that the `Assembly.Location` property returns the full path to the currently running assembly (exe or .dll). Trying to create a subdirectory under that will always fail.

Instead, you should use `Path.Combine` the directory part of the `Location` property with the subfolder (and then combine the result of that with the filename):

```
   var folder = Path.Combine(
       Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), 
            "resources", 
            "logging");
   var fullPath = Path.Combine(folder, file);
   Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
```

Answer (score 0):

This results in an invalid argument to GetDirectoryName():

```
_filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "/resources/logging/");
```

First, get the folder where the assembly is, then add on the rest of the path:

```
_filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "/resources/logging/";
```